# Has anyone had issues with parsing CVS-committed gettext .mo files?

Tags: cvs, gettext, mo

I have this issue where my `mo` parser code fails if I check out a `.mo` file from CVS ( CVS server is running on an old, old CENTOS box ) - I think CVS somehow corrupts it. If I use `poedit` and open the corresponding po file, and resave the mo over itself all is well.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what an `.mo` file is but the following might help since it's a common source of CVS file corruptions.

Do you have CVS treating it as a text file with keyword expansion and do you have some kind of text within this `.mo` file that resembles a cvs keyword? (`$author$` etc) CVS keywords here: http://ximbiot.com/cvs/manual/cvs-1.11.6/cvs_12.html